# Alias replaces ItemId on a component?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I was reading the document and it states that setting an alias in the form of

```
   'widget.xxx.yyy'
```

then the xtype would be automatically set to

```
   'xxx.yyy'
```

The problem I am having is that I have set up an alias and an itemId. It seems that the itemId is taking what is in the alias minus the `widget.` part.

Here's an example

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.product.Panel', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.productPanel',
    itemId: 'miscProductPanel',
```

So I am checking with the debugger and I notice the alias is correct, but the itemId seems to be now equal to "productPanel" and NOT "miscProductPanel".

Can anyone confirm what is happening ?

What's the real point of creating an alias ? Is there advantages of creating an alias. As far as I can see it seems to overwrite the itemID which I wasn't able to find in the documentation that this was a side affect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the alias is used as xtype while you create an object. ItemId is used to manage different objects of the same type.

for instance:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyNewButton', {
   extend : 'Ext.button.Button',
   alias: 'widget.myNewButton'
   ...
});
```

When I create my button on a panel I will do:

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    ...
    ...
    items:[{
       xtype:'myNewButton',
       itemId:'startBtn'
    },{
       xtype:'myNewButton',
       itemId:'stoptBtn'
    }]
});
```

You can use itemId to get each button.
For instance:

```
var startBtn = myPanel.down('myNewButton[itemId="startBtn"]');
var stopBtn = myPanel.down('myNewButton[itemId="stopBtn"]');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that, wherever you can, you should use `xtype: 'myNewButton'` instead of `alias`. `Alias` is "the old xtype", `xtype` is much faster. `xtype` is introduced to replace `alias` because of performance issues..

Comment: @Mattex83 Thanks for the comment. But what I was referring to is that if I create an itemId and an alias, the alias (without the widget. part) overwrites the itemId.

Comment: @Mattex83 see my original message.

Comment: @Tarabass problem is that there is some shared code that uses the widget i.e. Ext.ClassManager.getByAlias, and right now I can't change it. Will keep this in mind for when we can change the shared code. thanks

Comment: @Martin What I'm trying to say is that I think that you are using itemId in a wrong way and that's because it do not work properly.
you should:
* use xtype instead of alias as Tarabass said
* if you want to put an itemId for each object of your class I suggest you to assign it in the constructor